# How to enable Plone's advanced search box

Tags: plone

I have just recently installed Plone 4.2.1 using the unified installer,
on FreeBSD 8.3. My question is about the advanced search option, the
one that presents a long form with lots of different search options. 
The default seems to be a single text box. Can someone help to figure
out how to enable this on my site?

Answer (score 1):

In Plone 4.2, the options of the old advanced form have been integrated into the search results page; there is now a filter dropdown after you searched:

[image: search filter dropdown]

Changing options in this filter will automatically update the search results.

Comment: But I want all unpublished items only

Comment: @sureshvv The advance search feature was removed some time around 4.2b2 according to [this comment](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12811#comment:1) on the ticket system.  I was wondering where this went when I was updating documentation/screenshots for my products. Guess I have to look into reimplementing this sometime.